# property() returns different values

Tags: python, class, properties, python-2.x

I am trying to fill the gap in my understanding of Pythons `property()`.
Below is the code that I have come up with, to understand `property()`:

```
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self, temp = 10):
        self.set_temp(temp)

    def to_farenheit(self):
        return (self._temp * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temp(self):
        print "getting temperature value"
        return self._temp

    def set_temp(self, temp):
        print "setting temperature value"

        if temp < -237:
            raise ValueError("this shud be above -273")
        else:
            self._temp = temp

    temps = property(get_temp, set_temp)
```

I execute the above class and do the following:

```
>>> t = Temperature()
setting temperature value

>>> t.temps
getting temperature value
10

>>> t.temps = 13

>>> t.temps
13
>>> t.get_temp()
getting temperature value
10
>>>
```

As you can see above, when I try to set `temp` value by assigning `t.temps = 13` the `set_temp()` function is not getting called which I was expecting would be called because of `property()` functionality. Also I am ending up with 2 different values for variable `temp`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply because you use Python 2 and forgot to subclass `object`. In your case `property` simply doesn't work because it's an old-style class.

Better you subclass `object`:

```
class Temperature(object):
    ...
```

Or even better: Use Python 3. Python 3 doesn't have old-style classes anymore and you can omit the `(object)` part because it's implicit.

However you really shouldn't define `get_temp` or `set_temp` functions when you could use the decorator syntax. And you definitely shouldn't call them directly.

This would be much more pythonic:

```
class Temperature(object):
    def __init__(self, temp = 10):
        self.temps = temp

    def to_farenheit(self):
        return (self._temp * 1.8) + 32

    @property
    def temps(self):
        print("getting temperature value")
        return self._temp

    @temps.setter
    def temps(self, temp):
        print("setting temperature value")
        if temp < -237:
            raise ValueError("this shud be above -273")
        else:
            self._temp = temp
```

That example will work on Python 2 **and** Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

This problem only occurs in python 2.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

> class property([fget[, fset[, fdel[, doc]]]])
>
> Return a property attribute **for new-style classes** (classes that derive from object).

(Emphasis mine.)

If you make `Temperature` a new-style class by inheriting from `object`, the property will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use [new-style classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) which leverages [descriptors for properties](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

```
class Temperature(object):
    def __init__(self, temp=10):
        self.temps = temp

    def to_farenheit(self):
        return (self._temp * 1.8) + 32

    def get_temp(self):
        print "getting temperature value"
        return self._temp

    def set_temp(self, temp):
        print "setting temperature value"

        if temp < -237:
            raise ValueError("this shud be above -273")
        else:
            self._temp = temp

    temps = property(get_temp, set_temp)
```

This gives you the “right” behavior.

```
In [30]: t = Temperature()
setting temperature value

In [31]: t.temps
getting temperature value
Out[31]: 10

In [32]: t.temps = 100
setting temperature value

In [33]: t.temps
getting temperature value
Out[33]: 100

In [34]: t.__dict__
Out[34]: {'_temp': 100}
```